# HttpClient.PostAsync Hanging Until All System.Timers Are Started

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0, dotnet-httpclient

I'm having an odd problem with HttpClient and Timers. I have a large number of objects (up to 10,000) that post to a web service. These objects are on timers and post to the service at some n time after creation. The problem is that the Post stalls, until all of the timers have started. See the code below for an example.

**Q: Why does the Post hang until all Timers have started? How can it be fixed so that the post functions correctly while the other Timers start?**

```
public class MyObject
{
    public void Run()
    {
        var result = Post(someData).Result; 
        DoOtherStuff();
    }
}

static async Task<string> Post(string data)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        //Hangs here until all timers are started
        var response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(url), data).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
        var text = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);

        return text;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        TimeSpan delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        if (i % 2 == 0) delay = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);

        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.AutoReset = false;
        timer.Interval = delay.TotalMilliseconds;
        timer.Elapsed += (x, y) =>
            {
                MyObject o = new MyObject();
                o.Run();
            };

        timer.Start();
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're using up all the `ThreadPool` threads.

There's a lot wrong with your sample code. You're killing any chance of having reasonable performance, not to mention that the whole thing is inherently unstable.

You're creating a thousand timers in a loop. You're not keeping a reference to any of them, so they will be collected the next time the GC runs - so I'd expect that in practice, very few of them will actually run, unless there's very little memory allocated until they actually get to run.

The timer's `Elapsed` event will be invoked on a ThreadPool thread. In that thread, you synchronously wait for a bunch of asynchronous calls to complete. That means you're now wasting a thread pool thread, and completely wasting the underlying asynchronicity of the asynchronous method.

The continuation to the asynchronous I/O will be posted to ThreadPool as well - however, the ThreadPool is full of timer callbacks. It will slowly start creating more and more threads to accomodate the amount of work scheduled, until it finally is able to execute the first callback from the asynchronous I/O and it slowly untangles itself. At this point, you likely have more than 1000 threads, and are showing a complete misunderstanding of how to do asynchronous programming.

One way (still rather bad) to fix both problems is to simply make use of asynchronicity all the time:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public async Task Run()
    {
        var result = await Post(someData);
        DoOtherStuff();
    }
}

static async Task<string> Post(string data)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        //Hangs here until all timers are started
        var response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(url), new StringContent(data)).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
        var text = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);

        return text;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        TimeSpan delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        if (i % 2 == 0) delay = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);

        tasks.Add(Task.Delay(delay).ContinueWith((_) => new MyObject().Run()));
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

    Console.WriteLine("Work done");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

A much better way would be to implement some scheduler that handles dispatching the asynchronous I/O with the throttling you need. You probably want to limit the number of concurrent requests or something like that, rather than running the requests in pre-defined intervals (and ignoring the fact that some requests might take very long, timeout or some such).

Comment: FYI: `Task.Delay` also creates a new timer each time you call it: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs#5886

Comment: @Alxandr You're missing the point. One, the timer it creates is rooted, so it will not be collected by the GC until it elapses. Two, the thread is only necessary to start the asynchronous I/O operation, rather than blocking until it's done. In other words, even though it's still a bunch of timers, they are actually going to be using the ThreadPool rather efficiently.

Comment: Nono. I'm just pointing out that it still creates 1000 timers, whereas you'd only need 2.

Comment: @Alxandr Yeah, that's why I mentioned that it would be much smarter to implement a better tailored scheduler, rather than using a thousand timers. That would be beyond the scope of the answer. Of course, in this specific sample code (which most likely isn't what the OP wants) we're only really waiting either one second or one day, but I assume that's just a mistake OP made while coding the sample. I did say it was `still rather bad` solution, but it *does* solve the immediate problem the OP has.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in another reply, that `Result` property is the problem. when you are using it, `asyc` will be come `sync`. If you want to run async operations in console or windows service applications, try [Nito AsyncEx](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/) library. It creates an AsyncContext. Now you can change `void Run` to `Task Run` which is await-able and doesn't need the blocking `Result` property and in this case `await Post` will work in the `Run` method.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AsyncContext.Run(async () =>
    {
            var data = await ...;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the timers are set up very quickly so they have all finished setting up by the time `PostAsync` completes. Try putting a `Thread.Sleep(1000)` after `timer.Start`, this will slow down the set up of your timers and you should see some `PostAsync` executions complete.

By the way, `Task.Result` is a blocking operation, which can cause a deadlock when run from a GUI application. There is more information in this [article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As you're running on a console application, which uses the default ThreadPoolSynchronizationContext, you shouldn't really be experiencing the "hanging" feeling as if you are in a UI application. I assume its because `Post` is taking longer to return than to allocate 1000 timers.

In order for your method to run `async`, it has to go *"async all the way*. Using the `Task.Result` property, as mentioned before will simply block the asynchronous operation until it completes.

Lets see what we need to do for this to be "async all the way":

First, lets change `Run` from `void` to `async Task` so we can `await` on the `Post` method:

```
public async Task Run()
{
    var result = await Post(someData);
    DoOtherStuff();
}
```

Now, since `Run` became awaitable, as it returns a `Task`, we can turn `Timer.Elapsed` to an `async` event handler and `await` on `Run`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
   {
       TimeSpan delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
       if (i % 2 == 0) delay = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);

       System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
       timer.AutoReset = false;
       timer.Interval = delay.TotalMilliseconds;
       timer.Elapsed += async (x, y) =>
       {
            MyObject o = new MyObject();
            await o.Run();
       };

        timer.Start();
   }

   Console.ReadKey();
}
```

That's it, now we flow async all the way down to the HTTP request and back.

Comment: I think `async` event handlers should only be used in e.g. a winforms application, where they are eventually consumed. If I understand the problem correctly, this will cause any unhandled exceptions on the `Task`s to be thrown in the finalizer (thus crashing your whole application).

Comment: @Luaan im not sure why you have that understanding. async event handlers are mot limited to UI applications and exception handling is the same for console and UI in `async void` methods. As of .NET 4.5 the finializer does not crash the process on an unhandeled exception, but throws the `UnobservedTaskException`.

Comment: Okay, that does actually make sense. I've done most of my `Task` work in 4.0, so unobserved exceptions are something I take rather seriously (and it was the same with "manual" threading as well). Truth be told, I don't think it was such a good idea to allow unobserved exceptions like that...